# Почему я получаю ошибку sass is not a function в gulp при использовании модуля gulp-sass?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

У меня есть такой модуль для обработки стилей:

```
import autoPrefixer from "gulp-autoprefixer"
import groupCssMediaQueries from "gulp-group-css-media-queries"
import GulpCleanCss from "gulp-clean-css"
import dartSass from "sass"
import gulpSass from "gulp-sass"

const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);

export const scss = () => {
    return app.gulp.src(app.path.src.css, { sourcemaps: true })
        .pipe(app.plugins.cached("css"))
        .pipe(app.plugins.newer(app.path.build.css))
        .pipe(
            sass({
                outputStyle: "expanded"
            })
        )
        .pipe(
            groupCssMediaQueries()
        )
        .pipe(
            autoPrefixer({
                overrideBrowserslist: ["last 5 version"],
                cascade: true
            })
        )
        .pipe(app.plugins.remember("css"))
        .pipe(webpcss())
        .pipe(dest(app.path.build.css))
        .pipe(GulpCleanCss())
        .pipe(
            app.plugins.rename({
                extname: ".min.css"
            })
        )
        .pipe(app.gulp.dest(path.build.css))
        .pipe(app.plugins.browsersync.stream())
}
```

В `app.plugins` находятся общие для сбоки плагины, но это не важно. Тут

```
const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);
```

Я сохранил функцию gulpSass и передал в нее компилятор. То есть в `sass` по идее функция, но я получаю ошибку `sass is not a function`. При этом в [этом уроке](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU88mLuLWlk&t=1292s&ab_channel=%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8-IT%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81) у автора все работает (51:25) и [в документации](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass) предлагают подключать и использовать модуль именно так.

> To use gulp-sass in an ECMAScript module (which is supported in newer Node.js 14 and later), do something like this:
>
> ```
> import dartSass from 'sass';
> import gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
> const sass = gulpSass(dartSass);
> ```
>
> **Usage**
>
> gulp-sass must be used in a Gulp task. Your task can call sass() (to
> asynchronously render your CSS), or sass.sync() (to synchronously
> render your CSS).

Почему я получаю ошибку? Как это исправить, что я проглядел?

P.S. Объект находящийся в `sass`:

```
DestroyableTransform {
  _readableState: ReadableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    buffer: BufferList { length: 0 },
    length: 0,
    pipes: null,
    pipesCount: 0,
    flowing: null,
    ended: false,
    endEmitted: false,
    reading: false,
    sync: false,
    needReadable: true,
    emittedReadable: false,
    readableListening: false,
    resumeScheduled: false,
    destroyed: false,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    awaitDrain: 0,
    readingMore: false,
    decoder: null,
    encoding: null
  },
  readable: true,
  _events: [Object: null prototype] {
    end: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: onend] },
    prefinish: [Function: prefinish]
  },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _writableState: WritableState {
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 16,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: true,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function (anonymous)],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    bufferedRequest: null,
    lastBufferedRequest: null,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    bufferedRequestCount: 0,
    corkedRequestsFree: CorkedRequest {
      next: null,
      entry: null,
      finish: [Function (anonymous)]
    }
  },
  writable: true,
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  _transformState: {
    afterTransform: [Function: bound afterTransform],
    needTransform: false,
    transforming: false,
    writecb: null,
    writechunk: null,
    writeencoding: null
  },
  _destroyed: false,
  _transform: [Function (anonymous)],
  [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
}
```

Версия node js - `14.17.6`
Gulp `4.0.2`

Comment: `console.log(sass)`, node.js version...

Comment: @nörbörnën верисия node 14.17.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю, в чем была проблема. Чистил кэш npm, удалял и ставил sass и gulp-sass заново, ничего не помогло.

Я создал новый проект через `npm init`, перевел его в модульный режим и импортировал туда только нужные для функции модули - все заработало. Видимо модуль конфликтует с каким-то другим из моей старой сборки. Буду потихоньку инсталировать остальные, и если вылезет та же ошибка дополню ответ.